# Change values in time stamp

Tags: r, date

I have a time stamp  and I want to change the year which is not complete here.

Before:

```
23-11-17  12:53:41 PM
```

After: ( The way I want it to be)

```
23-11-2017 12:53:41 PM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can convert to datetime and then `format` it

```
format(as.POSIXct(str1, format = "%d-%m-%y %I:%M:%S %p"), "%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
#[1] "23-11-2017 12:53:41 PM"
```

---

Or using `regex`

```
sub("-(\\d{2})\\s+", "-20\\1 ", str1)
#[1] "23-11-2017 12:53:41 PM"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "23-11-17 12:53:41 PM"
```

Comment: This is a little off topic.                                                                     1. How can i extract the day(like there are 356/366 days in year, how can i extract  a day number for a particular date)                                                        2 How can i extract week number based on date

Comment: @KarthikShanmukha  You can check the `?strptime` where the different abbreivations for `format` is provided. The `%j` would give the day of year, week would be `%w` or `%W` depending on the requirement

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regex approach with `gsub`:

```
x <- "23-11-17 12:53:41 PM"
y <- gsub("(\\d{2}-\\d{2})-(\\d{2}) (\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} (?:AM|PM))",
          "\\1-20\\2 \\3", x)
y
[1] "23-11-2017 12:53:41 PM"
```

### Demo

Of course, this has the limitation that it assumes the century is always `20`, which may not be correct.  A more robust approach would be to convert to some R date class, then convert back to a string using a format mask with 4 digit years.